Early stop predicate with a `true` value in Prolog
I am writing a http_server application with http_sessions in Prolog. A request is handled with a dicontiguous (multiple definitions) predicate app, which must not fail (otherwise a 500 error appears to be given to the client). I need to early-quit the predicate somehow, so that the rest is not ran, but a custom message is shown and it ends without failure:
:- discontiguous app/1.

app(Request) :-
    ensure_path(Request), !, % I want a `!` after I determined the path is valid, so no other `app` is ran

    % grab session id as `Session`
    http_session_id(Session),
    
    % try to get session data, fail otherwise (I check something else in my code, but `http_session_data` should suffice for this example)
    (http_session_data(my_data(Data), Session); show_error, ...), % some syntactic magic here...
    
    % render something if session data has value
    render_some_success_html(Data).

Here is a piece of pseudocode of a non-Prolog language (don't scold me for comparing languages of different paradigms) that I am trying to do:
function app(request) {
    if (!ensure_path(request)) ...; // try other app(request)
    let session = http_session_id();
    let data = http_session_data('my_data', session);
    if (!data) {
        show_error();
        return true; // this is important
    }
    render_some_success_html(data);
}

I tried to use a !, fail in place of ..., but that does a failure (swipl says goal unexpectedly failed), and I need a true instead.
EDIT: there may be multiple such early-returns in the predicate, each one having own variant of show_error.

Prolog has e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=-%3E/2 for if..then..else logic. Or duplicate the predicate head. Also - predicates can call other predicates that you create. So you have the needed flexibility.

@brebs Does it allow me to simply early-return or does it require me to wrap the rest of the predicate in the Then case, and put the show_error into the Else case? (that would flip the order (can fix with \+) and cause a lot of nesting and unreadability). Duplicating the predicate head might be not an option because of the already existing multiple definitions. I would prefer if I could keep to success case at the bottom of the predicate, and predicates like show_error for some specific failure points, similar to the non-Prolog example code.

You can go ahead and write any language style in any other language. It is going to be less pleasant though.

The point of the early-returns is to make the code not too nested, and to keep it top down, with the failure actions close to those checks, making it much more readable.
Thanks to @TA_intern 's suggestion I decided to use two variants of that predicate(Args) on each failure point. The following code will use the ! variant, but the reader may try out the new "Picat" syntax as well.
So here is my solution:

Split the predicate into multiple ones upon such failure points.
Given a simple example of a chain of dependent calls, each giving some result for the next bit in the chain to consume:
predicate_with_failure_points(In1) :-
    failure_point1(In1, Out1),  % want to `show_error1` else on fail
    failure_point2(Out1, Out2), % and `show_error2` here
    success(Out2).

The split will look like:
predicate_with_failure_point1(In1) :-
    failure_point1(In1, Out1), !, % `!` is not strictly necessary, but it might save a lot of headaches, might be necessary when dealing with side-effects 
    predicate_with_failure_point2(Out1).

predicate_with_failure_point2(In2) :-
    failure_point2(In2, Out2), !,
    success(Out2). % could split this bit here, especially if `success` is not a single line of code but quite large and would put `show_error2` too far down. let's assume this `success` is already a split off part.


Give each predicate an alternative variant as a handler for that failure point.
predicate_with_failure_point1(In1) :-
    failure_point1(In1, Out1), !,
    predicate_with_failure_point2(Out1).
predicate_with_failure_point1(In1) :- % will execute if `!` was not reached
    show_error1(In1).

predicate_with_failure_point2(In2) :-
    failure_point2(In2, Out2), !,
    success(Out2).
predicate_with_failure_point2(In2) :-
    show_error2(In2).



The resulting code:

does not proceed executing the rest of (original) code upon failure;
goes from top to bottom, without unnecessary nesting or flipping parts of the code;
puts a show_error right next to the failure point.

The example given in the original question would then look like following:
:- discontiguous app/1.

app(Request) :-
    ensure_path(Request), !,
    http_session_id(Session),
    check_session_data(Session).

check_session_data(Session) :-
    http_session_data(my_data(Data), Session), !,
    render_some_success_html(Data).
check_session_data(_Session) :-
    show_error.


One recent addition for SWI-Prolog to support a more "functional" programming style is, instead of:
predicate_head(Args...) :- Body

you can do:
predicate(Args), Condition1 => Body1.
predicate(Args), Condition2 => Body2.
...
predicate(Args) => Default.

It is evaluated top to bottom; it commits to the first condition that fits; and it fails at run-time if you don't have a default at the bottom and none of the conditions were true.
All of this is documented here: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ssu
Please try to read it through because it shows how to write Prolog programs without it, and how to write the same programs with it. I strongly suspect it will help you with your current question.

I already had a !, Guard in the question's example ;) Using a single Condition1 though (for question's example it would be http_session_data, and show_error being your Default), it is possible to somewhat adapt it to what I wanted, although by defining some extra predicates instead of doing it all in one. Maybe an SWI-Prolog feature request can be put somewhere for something like complete to also be early stopping like fail but with a true instead?

@KirillSemyonkin you can do that with a conditional, ( Cond -> Then ; Else ). This is also in the linked docs that you already read. But your own answer already looks quite good. Both conditionals and SSU are different tools that provide alternatives to the style in your answer. I don't know that the Prolog programming community would be too dogmatic about style, one issue is that the different alternatives provide trade-offs depending on the specific case; in other words, use your judgement :)
